# Часто перезагружается рабочий стол

Tags: windows

Здравствуйте!  У меня проблема: часто перезагружается рабочий стол, пишет - перезагрузить проводник, хотя в этот момент папки не открыты и система не загружена. Windows 7.

Comment: антивирусом проверял ничего не нашёл

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотри в Панели управления Просмотр событий: Панель управления - Система и безопасность - Администрирование - Просмотр событий.В Просмотр событий слева выбери Журналы Windows, далее Система. В появившемся списке найти события как-либо связанные с проблемой. Смотри примерно по времени и уровню ошибки. Скорее всего будет ошибка (могут быть варианты: сведения, предупреждение, ошибка).Исходя из этого можно будет дальше думать.

Answer (score 0):

Проверить антивирусом надобно,у меня аналогичное было;проверил-нашел-удалил тогда помогло правда уже точно не вспомню нахождение этой причины но произошло это после посещения "развлекательного" сайта

Answer (score 0):

В последнее время заметил эпидемию вирусов под 7кой.Попробуйте drweb у них утилита есть без платная drweb cureit